# Spyder type auto prediction requires 3 characters minimum

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am using Spyder as my Python IDE instead of Pycharm. Its editor provides predictions quite fast but it needs at least 3 characters for them to be shown.

Can I change this? My problem is I have similar variables with long names, so having faster completions would be great.

Comment: Check out the preferences completions & timing section.  You should attempt to read the docs before asking this type of question.

Comment: @itprorh66, unfortunately we don't have docs for this yet.

Comment: @itprorh66 thanks for recommending. I did but juped 'Completion and linting'  tab

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Yeah thats absolutelly true, I had searhed on ddg & google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To decrease or increase the number of characters needed to get completions, please go to the menu:

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Code completion`

and change the number in `Show automatic completions after characters entered`.